Окончание в слове "тысяча"
Подскажите, пожалуйста: Техникум подготовил около 6,5 тысяч (или тысячИ) дипломированных специалистов. Спасибо)

Техникум подготовил около 6,5 тысячи дипломированных специалистов.
Ответ «Грамоты»: «В сочетании с дробным числительным существительное ставится в форме единственного числа родительного падежа».

Ответы справочной службы
Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста: Техникум подготовил 
около 6,5 тысяч (или тысячИ) дипломированных специалистов. 
Спасибо)

Правильно: Техникум подготовил около 6,5 тысячи 
дипломированных специалистов.

Пояснение
6,5 тысячи — это шесть и пять десятых (долей) тысячи (Р.п. ед.ч.)
